# Need to transfer touch & sensor data from one device to another connected through WIFI Direct

Tags: android, data-transfer, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I have made a simple multiplayer game , in which a player can select any of the available choices . I want to sync the choices between devices, i.e two devices are connected through Wifi direct but i dont know how to get the choice selected by another player & vice versa

Answer (score 0):

So if the question simply on how would you get the connection done ? or is there something else ?
Basically, you would use the API as it is designed, you add a local service, and then start Service discovery and then once you find the service you start connecting. Then once you get connection event, simply fetch the connection information to see which one got to be group owner and which one got to be client. And as the client now knows the IP address of the Group owner, you can do normal connections between the devices.

If you are ok having BT connections, you could always try using my library, which is included in [Thali/BtConApp](https://github.com/DrJukka/BTConApp) sample app.